# Estimation of the mean of a long tailed distribution

Tags: mean, autocorrelation, heavy-tailed

I want to calculate the average of a data set in which elements are distributed according to a PDF that seems to have a quite long tail. This means that when I bin elements of this set I get a PDF that is somewhat between Gaussian and Cauchy distribution, falls off quicker than Cauchy and slower than Gauss. The median seems to work quite well for sets that have symmetric distributions, but some of the sets are skewed. The sample mean is too noisy.

Is there a fairly cheap and efficient way of estimating the average?

Comment: Well, the sample mean is calculated in the usual way, and the underlying distribution does not matter. What is your question?

Comment: True, but if you have a Gaussian distribution sample average converges faster with the number of data points, compared to a longer tailed distribution (which might not converge at all in some cases, I guess). My question is if there is a better estimator on a finite set of points (I can not have infinitely large dataset)?

Comment: By [Gauss-Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem), the sample mean is still the BLUE for the mean. Are you willing to accept bias, or what objective do you want to minimize, if not the variance of your estimator?

Comment: Alright, so if I want an unbiased estimator I can not do better than the sample mean. Is that still true if I know what is the underlying PDF?

Comment: You can do better when you make parametric assumptions about the PDF.  However, experience (especially with lognormal distributions) shows us that those assumptions had better be *very good models,* for otherwise the parametric methods can be worse than the sample mean. It's most important that the distribution family accurately model the extreme data values--but almost by definition that's impossible to verify unless you have huge amounts of data or a really rigorous theory (typically available only in theoretical physics experiments).

Comment: I actually have a good guess of what my PDF should be. I have a Gaussian random variable that I autocorrelate and this autocorrelation is the dataset for which I am trying to find the mean. If I am correct in interpreting answers to different questions I found on this site, the PDF in question should be the Bessel function. Unfortunately, it does not have a nice closed form, as far as I know, so I could parameterize it by fitting.

Comment: You could be better off asking about this specific problem. Also, I do not understand how tha samplig distribution of an autocorrelation can have long tails ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I will post a new question with more details. Thank you for the suggestion.